# did not call through super.oncreate and am sure i added thet super.oncreate

Tags: java, android

**Mainpage.java**

```
public class Mainpage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainpage);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //  setupActionBar();
    }
```

**LogCat:**

```
04-17 05:25:47.687: D/dalvikvm(1034): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 5% free 2785K/2924K, paused 75ms, total 79ms
04-17 05:25:47.717: I/dalvikvm-heap(1034): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.473MB for 720016-byte allocation
04-17 05:25:47.797: D/dalvikvm(1034): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3485K/3628K, paused 76ms, total 76ms
04-17 05:25:48.057: D/AndroidRuntime(1034): Shutting down VM
04-17 05:25:48.057: W/dalvikvm(1034): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a44b90)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): Process: com.example.thatmoment, PID: 1034
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.thatmoment/com.example.thatmoment.Mainpage} did not call through to super.onCreate()
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2142)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-17 05:25:48.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 05:28:09.387: I/Process(1034): Sending signal. PID: 1034 SIG: 9
```

Comment: And this is the same version of the code you're running and not an older one?

Comment: Try to clean your project.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: any solution to problem?